# WGL extension and virtualbox

Tags: opengl, virtualbox, wgl, rendermonkey

I'm currently trying to use the old Rendermonkey 1.82 on a WinXP virtual machine running in VirtualBox 4.3.8. Sadly it doesn't work for OpenGL, unable to find WGL extensions (exact error msg is: "WGL PBuffer extensions not detected - please update your driver. Won't be able to proceed with OpenGL rendering.")... 
Even if the program works using DirectX, I need it for use with OpenGL

Do you know it there is a solution/workaround to this problem?

Consider also that:
- DirectX based 3D acceleration works just fine
- other OpenGL based programs works just fine
- 3D acceleration is enabled in the vm setting
- Updated GuestAddition installed and working

Comment: Do you have up to date drivers?  What kind of GPU do you have?

Comment: Drivers on the VM are supposed to be updated, since they mainly depend on the GuestAdditions... Those on my host are indeed up-to-date. I suppose the problem is in the VirtualBox OpenGL WGL extension support, but I'm not sure nor I know if there is a solution... if indeed the problem is this

(Host video cards: Intel HD Graphics 4000 (integrated) and NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M